# error turning off default printer please help

Tags: printer

hi guys i think i found a bug with latest elementary os release under system settings printer if i click the i (information) button it pops up with a option to print test page and a check box saying set as default printer. i checked to use as my default printer but when i tried to uncheck as default printer it would not let me the box wont let me unclick can someone else try this and see if they have the same issue. thanks [image: default printer wont uncheck]

Answer (score 1):

As you have only one printer in the list, you could not set another one as default. I guess this is really rather a feature than a bug.